# Adding hibernate-ehcache.jar and ehcache-core.jar to WildFly as a module

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly, ehcache, hibernate-cache

Configuring a cache provider in `persistence.xml` along with some other related properties as follows.

```xml
<shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>

<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="allow"/>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />

    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
</properties>
```

This works, when the following two JAR files are added to the compile-time class-path of the EE module itself.

- hibernate-ehcache-5.0.6.Final.jar
- ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar

Is it allowed to add these JAR files to the server itself as a module as these JAR files are not required to be present on the compile-time class-path?

I get an exception, when a module like the following is attempted at `${Home}/modules/system/layers/base/net/sf/ehcache/main/module.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="net.sf.ehcache">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-ehcache-5.0.6.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.hibernate"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

It causes the following exception to be thrown as if it has no effect at all.

```
15:53:32,671 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."WildFly.ear/WildFly-ejb.jar#org.hibernate.project.unit".__FIRST_PHASE__: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."WildFly.ear/WildFly-ejb.jar#org.hibernate.project.unit".__FIRST_PHASE__: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:665)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:40)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.<init>(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:39)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.getBootstrap(HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$800(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:118)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:71)
    ... 24 more
```

Is it not allowed to add these two JAR files to the server as a module or there exists a different way to achieve this?

---

The module `org.hibernate` contains the following resources along with their dependencies.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.hibernate">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-envers-5.0.6.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.6.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.classmate"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.jandex"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.infinispan" services="import" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate4-3" services="import"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

---

I use Hibernate 5.0.6 final in WildFly 9.0.2 final.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do theses steps :

1. Add hibernate-ehcache.jar in you main hibernate module;
2. Add ehcache like a wildfly module. You have to create a folder :
   [wildfly]/modules/system/layers/base/net/sf/ehcache/main with ehcache jar and module.xml.
3. Make reference to ehcache module in main hibernate module.xml.

Regards

Steve

Comment: Referencing `<module name="net.sf.ehcache"/>` in the Hibernate main module had already been attempted prior to the question. The same exception is caused.

Answer (score 0):

In Wildfly (e.g. version 10), you can use Infinispan (JSR107 compatible) to do a L2 cache instead. 
At modules directory of wildfly - org/hibernate/main/module.xml, you've to use like these (no need to specify "hibernate-ehcache-5.0.11.Final.jar"):

```
 <resource-root path="hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar"/>
 <resource-root path="hibernate-envers-5.0.11.Final.jar"/>
 <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar"/>
 <resource-root path="hibernate-java8-5.0.11.Final.jar"/>
```

WildFly server is loaded a default with Infinispan.

In your persistance.xml, configuration will be:

```
 <!-- enable query cache -->
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
  <!-- EhCache provider-->
  <!-- <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/> -->
  <!-- 2nd level cache -->
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
  <!-- enable statistics -->
  <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
  <!-- for Wildfly only -->
  <property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="org.hibernate.search.orm:5.5.5.Final"/>
```